# Spring Ehcache : Delete entries by a condition like endDate > now

Tags: spring, scala, caching, ehcache, spring-el

I would like to delete entries that satisfy a condition(e.g : Delete entries endDate > now) using annotation provided by Spring over Ehcache, maybe with a SpEl expression.

Something like that :

```
 @CacheEvict(value = Array("intensities"), condition = "samples.end > now")
 def save(samples: Samples[Intensity]) = {
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more advanced eviction features are specific to the underlying Ehcache implementation, therefore they are not configurable through the basic abstractions offered by Spring. See sections `28.5.2` and `28.7` in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

You can configure the eviction behavior of Ehcache in the `ehcache.xml` file. Though not exactly the same what your code tries to achieve, the `timeToLiveSeconds` attribute might be the one you are looking for. See the [Ehcache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/data-life#24283) for more details.

## Update

On second thought, the following SpEL expression does exactly what you intended to do, without touching the Ehcache specific settings:

```
@CacheEvict(
    value = Array("intensities"),
    condition = "samples.end.after(new java.util.Date())")
def save(samples: Samples[Intensity]) = {
   ...
}
```